# Using $refs in a computed property

Tags: vue.js

How do I access `$refs` inside computed? It's always undefined the first time the computed property is run.

Comment: Yes it's defined only when the first render loop is done. For what it worth, it's explicitly not recommended to use $refs inside computed properties as it is not reactive. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs You may have to find a better pattern...

Comment: Using **Watch function** inside of the mounted:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225378/how-to-watch-child-properties-changes-from-parent-component)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here, I couldn't find a satisfactory answer anywhere else. Sometimes you just need access to a dom element to make some calculations. Hopefully this is helpful to others.

I had to trick Vue to update the computed property once the component was mounted.

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  data(){
    return {
      isMounted: false
    }
  },
  computed:{
    property(){
      if(!this.isMounted)
        return;
      // this.$refs is available
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.isMounted = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: Had exactly the same requirement and this was the only workable solution I found. Bound the class property to a computed property and had to apply some classes if a nested component (the ref) had some properties set.

Comment: very helpful, thanks @EricGuan for taking the time to answer your own question to help others

Comment: The thing is, there doesn't seem to be a guarantee that the `$refs` you need actually exist during `mounted`... It's hit or miss for me.

Comment: Vue is so clean, intuitive, and efficient to use (I personally think it's the best UI framework today). But, it has a problem. I've found that things can get ugly/messy when your stuff depends on DOM sizes/computations/etc. 

I'd love to see an article about "Using Vue when your UI depends on DOM elements".

I understand the idea of "anti-patterns", but things like website widgets that get embedded within other websites can't always just "follow another pattern".

I wonder if this post could be that missing puzzle piece of Vue. O.o

Comment: @Douglas Gaskell, I haven't tried this, but maybe try waiting a tick using a nextTick() inside mounted() before setting this.isMounted = true. I'm thinking that this.$refs should be ready by then.
https://gist.github.com/tomknappramos/b9c178c5cd56e26d9c694f32f290cd26

Comment: While this initially worked, it's not reactive, when the refs change, it doesn't update, for instance, clientWidth is static, as if it only gets the initial size on mounted, and if the object changes, it doesn't update.

Comment: Causes issues with testing, especially if the expected result is some value and instead we return something else ( in your case, undefined ). But otherwise neat!

Comment: P.S. just use nextTick() while testing and all will be fine!

Comment: NextTick doesn't work if components are loaded asynchronously. The way I get $refs is instead to use setInterval (bind to a constant) in the mounted lifecyclehook. In the callback function, check if this.$refs is not undefined. If that is true, clearInterval and set isMounted to true. Inspired by https://jefrydco.id/en/blog/safe-access-vue-refs-undefined/#safe-way

Answer (score 32):

I think it is important to quote the [Vue js guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements):

> $refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and they are not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid accessing $refs from within templates or computed properties.

It is therefore not something you're supposed to do, although you can always hack your way around it.

Answer (score 21):

If you need the `$refs` after an `v-if` you could use the `updated()`  hook.

```html
<div v-if="myProp"></div>
```

```js
updated() {
    if (!this.myProp) return;
    /// this.$refs is available
},
```

Comment: neat trick!  Incorporate the `v-if` conditionals in the `computed`'s logic so they get registered as dependencies.  Exactly the answer to a curiosity of an element with `ref` and toggled by `v-if`

Comment: or put the code to access $refs inside nextTick: this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs...)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer multiple times. You saved me!

Comment: First time I see a good use case for the updated hook. Thanks 

Answer (score 11):

I just came with this same problem and realized that this is the type of situation that computed properties will not work.

According to the current documentation (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

"[...]**Instead of a computed property, we can define the same function as a method. For the end result, the two approaches are indeed exactly the same. However, the difference is that computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed**"

So, what (probably) happen in these situations is that finishing the mounted lifecycle of the component and setting the refs doesn't count as a reactive change on the dependencies of the computed property.

For example, in my case I have a button that need to be disabled when there is no selected row in my ref table.
So, this code will not work:

```
<button :disabled="!anySelected">Test</button>

computed: {
    anySelected () {
      if (!this.$refs.table) return false

      return this.$refs.table.selected.length > 0
    }
}
```

What you can do is replace the computed property to a method, and that should work properly:

```
<button :disabled="!anySelected()">Test</button>

methods: {
    anySelected () {
      if (!this.$refs.table) return false

      return this.$refs.table.selected.length > 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this approach is the best one so far. It doesn't spread the instructions out to `data()`, `updated()`, and other parts. Clean and concise.

Comment: Methods are not reactive and won't be updated if the ref property changes.

Answer (score 4):

For others users like me that need just pass some data to prop, I used `data` instead of `computed`

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
    data(){
        return {
            myProp: null
        }
    },    
    mounted(){
        this.myProp= 'hello'    
        //$refs is available              
        // this.myProp is reactive, bind will work to property
    }
})
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer if you do not need it to be reactive.

Answer (score 1):

Use property binding if you want. :disabled prop is reactive in this case

```html
<button :disabled="$refs.email ? $refs.email.$v.$invalid : true">Login</button>
```

But to check two fields i found no other way as dummy method:

```html
<button :disabled="$refs.password ? checkIsValid($refs.email.$v.$invalid, $refs.password.$v.$invalid) : true">
  {{data.submitButton.value}}
</button>
```

```js
methods: {
   checkIsValid(email, password) {
      return email || password;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation and I fixed it with:

```
  data: () => {
   return { 
    foo: null,
   }, // data
```

And then you watch the variable:

```
    watch: {
     foo: function() {
       if(this.$refs)
        this.myVideo = this.$refs.webcam.$el;
       return null;
      },
    } // watch
```

Notice the `if` that evaluates the existence of `this.$refs` and when it changes you get your data.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to store the references into a data property. Then, I populate this data attribute in mounted event.

```
    data() {
        return {
            childComps: [] // reference to child comps
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // method to populate the data array
        getChildComponent() {
            var listComps = [];
            if (this.$refs && this.$refs.childComps) {
                this.$refs.childComps.forEach(comp => {
                    listComps.push(comp);
                });
            }
            return this.childComps = listComps;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        // Populates only when it is mounted
        this.getChildComponent();
    },
    computed: {
        propBasedOnComps() {
            var total = 0;
            // reference not to $refs but to data childComps array
            this.childComps.forEach(comp => {
                total += comp.compPropOrMethod;
            });
            return total;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to avoid $refs completely and just subscribe to events from the child component.

It requires an explicit setter in the child component, but it is reactive and not dependent on mount timing.

Parent component:

```html
<script>
{
  data() {
    return {
      childFoo: null,
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <Child @foo="childFoo = $event" />

    <!-- reacts to the child foo property -->
    {{ childFoo }}

  </div>
</template>
```

Child component:

```js
{
  data() {
    const data = {
      foo: null,
    }
    this.$emit('foo', data)
    return data
  },
  emits: ['foo'],
  methods: {
    setFoo(foo) {
      this.foo = foo
      this.$emit('foo', foo)
    }
  }
}

<!-- template that calls setFoo e.g. on click -->
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, brb