# How to watch child properties changes from parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a date picker component library and i want to watch when a property of that component changes.

I have tried this:

```
  watch: {
    '$refs.picker.popupVisible': {
      handler (new_value) {
        console.log('executed')
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

Also this:

```
  computed: {
    picker () {
      console.log(this.$refs.picker.popupVisible)
      return this.$refs.picker.popupVisible
    }
  }
```

I know that the solution will be a vue.js hack because this is not the right way.If i had access to child component i would emit en event to parent but unfortunately i don't have.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had a similar problem using a library which had some limitations.

Unfortunately, your watcher will not work.You have to use the **function watcher** to make this to work.And you have to use it inside the `mounted` hook.

```
  mounted() {
    this.$watch(
      "$refs.picker.popupVisible",
      (new_value, old_value) => {
         //execute your code here
      }
    );
  }
```

I also have an example. Please [take a look here](https://codesandbox.io/s/yk1l5zp9l9)

Comment: Is there an explanation on why `watch: {}` won't work?

Comment: I am not sure but I guess `watch: {}` can be used for components properties whilst `vm.$watch()` it is not limited to the component instance. So in that case watching from parent, child properties for changes with `watch: {}` it does not work. `vm.$watch()` works perfect though.

Comment: I suspect it doesn't work because at the time `watch{}` is created, the child components haven't been mounted, and therefore the reactivity can't be set up. By doing it with `this.$watch()`, that is happening after the child components have mounted, so the reactivity does work.

Comment: Should we also unwatch this in beforeDestroy?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a data object in parent component and include the date field in that data object and pass that data object to child component as props

```
<child :dateObj="dateObj"></child>
data: {
  dateObj: {
    date: ""
  }
}
```

And in child component you can use the `date` field of that `dateObj` props. This is possible because **Vue doesn't watch the property of Objects passed as props and we can modify them without Vue complaining in console.**

Thus the changed date field is reflected in parent as well.