# Watch child properties from parent component in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I'm wondering how I can observe child properties from the parent component in Vue 3 using the composition api (I'm working with the experimental [script setup](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md)).

```html
<template>//Child.vue
  <button 
    @click="count++" 
    v-text="'count: ' + count" 
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

let count = ref(1)
</script>
```

```html
<template>//Parent.vue
  <p>parent: {{ count }}</p> //update me with a watcher
  <Child ref="childComponent" />
</template>


<script setup>
import Child from './Child.vue'
import { onMounted, ref, watch } from 'vue'

const childComponent = ref(null)
let count = ref(0)

onMounted(() => {
  watch(childComponent.count.value, (newVal, oldVal) => {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
    count.value = newVal
  })
}) 
</script>
```

I want to understand how I can watch changes in the child component from the parent component. My not working solution is inspired by the [Vue.js 2 Solution asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225378/how-to-watch-child-properties-changes-from-parent-component). So I don't want to emit the `count.value` but just watch for changes.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you want to emit the event?

Comment: Because I want to understand how to observe changed data across components. The counting is only just an example. It's not an exotic case, but unfortunately I'm not getting anywhere, so that' s why I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bindings inside of `<script setup>` are "closed by default" as you can see [here](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md#closed-by-default).

However you can explicitly expose certain refs.
For that you use `useContext().expose({ ref1,ref2,ref3 })`

So simply add this to Child.vue:

```js
import { useContext } from 'vue'

useContext().expose({ count })
```

and then change the Watcher in Parent.vue to:

```js
watch(() => childComponent.value.count, (newVal, oldVal) => {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
    count.value = newVal
  })
```

And it works!

Comment: Both of your suggestions have no effect. `childComponent.value.count` is undefined. I know that it is solved via emit and props. As I said I am interested in the example.

Comment: Have you changed your Code in Child.vue?
from
```<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

let count = ref(1)
</script>
```
to
```<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
export default {
    setup(){
    const count = ref(1)

    return {
      count
    }
  }
}
</script>```
? 
It works for me.

Comment: Hey Tom, no sorry. I want to work with the `script setup` method. I can try it out with it if you like. Maybe this will bring me further to apply the basics to the experimental version.

Comment: It seems like what you are trying to do is not yet possible with the `script setup` method. Take a look at this topic (closed by default) in the RFC https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/script-setup-2/active-rfcs/0000-script-setup.md#closed-by-default . It's intended that the bindings are not exposed in the parent component.
Note: "How to explicitly expose imperative public interface will be finalized in https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/210."

Comment: I have edited my response, there is already a way to expose refs with the `<script setup>` syntax!

Comment: Works fine, thank you. I hope you will use the script setup as well (when it finally gets approved)

Answer (score 2):

I've answered the [Vue 2 Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225443/6385184)
and it works perfectly fine with Vue 3 **if you don't use `script setup` or explicitly expose properties**.

Here is the working code.

**Child.vue**

```html
<template>
  <button @click="count++">Increase</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      count: ref(0),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Parent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Child ref="childComponent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import Child from './components/Child.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Child,
  },
  setup() {
    const childComponent = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
      watch(
        () => childComponent.value.count,
        (newVal) => {
          console.log({ newVal }) // runs when count changes
        }
      );
    });

    return { childComponent };
  },
};
</script>
```

[See it live on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-aempd4?)

---

## Please keep reading

In the [Vue 2 Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225443/6385184) I have described that we should use the **mounted hook** in order to be able to watch child properties.
In Vue 3 however, that's no longer an issue/limitation since the watcher has additional options like `flush: 'post'` which ensures that the element has been rendered.

Make sure to read the [Docs: Watching Template Refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#watching-template-refs)

---

When using `script setup`, **the public instance of the component it's not exposed** and thus, the Vue 2 solutions will not work.
In order to make it work you need to explicitly expose properties:

#### With script setup

import { ref } from 'vue'

const a = 1
const b = ref(2)

defineExpose({
  a,
  b
})

#### With Options API

```
export default {
  expose: ['publicData', 'publicMethod'],
  data() {
    return {
      publicData: 'foo',
      privateData: 'bar'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    publicMethod() {
      /* ... */
    },
    privateMethod() {
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}
```

*Note:* If you define `expose` in Options API then only those properties will be exposed. The rest will not be accessible from template refs or $parent chains.