# Vue: Property or method is not defined on the instance

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 components (Q1 and RepConfig). I am trying to import the Q1 component in the RepConfig so I can use it over and over again. The Q1 component points to a Vue store (dscpValues.js) with a simple array:

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        dscpData: [
            { id: 'cs0', value: 'CS0' },
            { id: 'cs1', value: 'CS1' },
            { id: 'cs2', value: 'CS2' },
            { id: 'cs3', value: 'CS3' },
            { id: 'cs4', value: 'CS4' },
            { id: 'cs5', value: 'CS5' },
            { id: 'cs6', value: 'CS6' },
            { id: 'cs7', value: 'CS7' }
        ]
    }
};
```

Q1 Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul v-for="(option, index) in dscpValues.dscpData" :key="index">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" class="inputMarginRight" :id="option.id" :value="option.value" v-model="dscpChoiceQ1" />
                <label for="id">{{ option.value }}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import { ref, computed } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['dscpValues'])
    },
    setup() {
        const dscpChoiceQ1 = ref([]);
        const dscpValuesQ1 = computed({
            get: () => {
                const v = dscpChoiceQ1.value;

                return v.join(' ');
            },
            set: (newval) => {
                dscpChoiceQ1.value = newval;
            }
        });

        return {
            dscpChoiceQ1,
            dscpValuesQ1
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

RepConfig Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <queue-one></queue-one>
    </div>
    <span>{{ dscpValuesQ1 }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import QueueOne from './QueueNumber/Q1';

export default {
    components: {
        QueueOne
    }
}
</script>
```

I get the "Method or property dscpValuesQ1 is not defined on the instance but referenced during render". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `<span>{{ dscpValuesQ1 }}</span>` the `dscpValuesQ1` is `undefined` in the `RepConfig Component`

Comment: Yeah so how do I point to the imported component's `dscpValuesQ1`?

Comment: You can use `scoped-slot` to pass data from Child to Parent.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the value `dscpValuesQ1` in the RepConfig component, when it seems to be stored in the child QueueOne (Q1) component (which points to the VueX store). Parent components don't have access to the data of their children by default.

You can access the data by adding the same VueX connectivity to your parent component and getting the value that way, or by adding a ref on the child component in the parent component's template, with a watch on your parent component that watches changes on your child component ([as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225378/how-to-watch-child-properties-changes-from-parent-component)). For example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <queue-one ref="q1"></queue-one>
    </div>
    <span>{{ dscpValuesQ1 }}</span>
</template>

<script>
import QueueOne from './QueueNumber/Q1';

export default {
    components: {
        QueueOne
    },

    mounted() {
        this.$watch("$refs.q1.dscpValuesQ1", (new_value, old_value) => {
            // Store data in this (parent) component
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This makes sense but I am still getting `dscpValuesQ1 undefined` ...

Comment: Are you able to post a JSFiddle? I'm guessing that you are getting the error because you aren't checking if the variable exists before you try and use it. Maybe add a v-if onto the element where you try to use the variable?