# TypeError this.$refs.password is undefined in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this error in my front. I try to use length's errorBucket for v-progress-linear (Vuetify) (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#progress)

Template

```
                    <v-form
                        ref="form"
                        v-model="valid"
                        lazy-validation
                    >
                    ...
                                <v-text-field
                                    ref="password"
                                    :rules="[rules.required, rules.min, rules.space, nom, prenom, rules.contain]"
                                    counter
                                    loading
                                >
                                    <template v-slot:progress>
                                        <v-progress-linear
                                            v-if="custom"
                                            :value="progress"
                                            :color="color"
                                        ></v-progress-linear>
                                    </template>
                                </v-text-field>
                    </v-form>
```

Script

```
computed: {
        progress () {

            return Math.min(100, (6-this.$refs.password.errorBucket.length) * (100/6))

        },
        color () {

                var couleur = '';

                var errors = this.$refs.password.errorBucket.length;

                if(errors > 2){
                    couleur = 'error'
                }else if(errors == 1 || errors == 2){
                    couleur = 'warning'
                }else{
                    couleur = 'success'
                }    
                
                return couleur;
 
        },
}
```

Error when i open modal

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.$refs.password is undefined"
TypeError: this.$refs.password is undefined
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: IntersectionObserver.observe: Argument 1 does not implement interface Element."
TypeError: IntersectionObserver.observe: Argument 1 does not implement interface Element.
```

If somebody have a solution, I thank you in advance.

Comment: where did you define `password` as a `ref`?

Comment: @hamidniakan i update my post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53556796/6178832

Comment: $refs are not reactive and should not be used in computed. Even if you bypass the TypeError, your function will not work

Comment: @SølveTornøe Do you know how to access number of errors from rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refactor your computed like this:

```
progress() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    // your code goes here
  });
}
```

by wrapping your code in `this.$nextTick` you can make sure that your code runs when everything is rendered and you have completed access to `refs` defined in your template.